# How to fix error in this emulator?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Am trying to generate emulator at visual studio 2017 and always this error appears .

[image: error]

Comment: Did you try googling at all? Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What's the error? Would you add it as text as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Build Action of 'storyoapp.png' to `AndroidResource`.  Xamarin does not support the `Content` build action and will throw an error ([Xamarin.Android Build Process information](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/))